# hitting a controller method from aspx view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working in a plugin that uses .net MVC controllers and .aspx views, I'm returning views from methods but I can not find any reference on how to make a URL to another controller method that returns a view. I have tried the rezar standard but it does not work in aspx

Comment: Are you just looking for the `Html.ActionLink()` helper?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2  Or perhaps `Url.Action()`?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2  By ".aspx views" do you mean you are using WebForms pages?  In that case you may just need to create it manually, or in your server-side code expose some common functionality your WebForms pages can call.  What specifically are you trying and how specifically is it failing?

Comment: These .aspx pages, are they in the Views folder? The ASPX view engine can be used in older version of ASP.NET MVC (as an alternative to Razor .cshtml), but it is far more common that .aspx is a full blown Web Forms page.